# Git is unable to access jarfile on Windows. No backslash characters are showing up in file path

Tags: windows, git, backslash

I'm trying to integrate a checkstyle.xml file into a pre-compile git hook.

I successfully ran the command

```
git config --add checkstyle.xml C:\Users\<user>\Documents\<App-Name>\CheckStyle\checkstyle.xml
```

However, now when I try to commit I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:Users<user>Documents<AppName>...
```

Notice that the backslashes don't exist. I looked at the git config file and each backslash has another backslash in front of it as an escape character.

Does git not recognize any backslashes? I tried adding the file with forward slashes instead of back and I get that the jarfile is corrupt. Any help would be appreciated.

edit:
Paul Hicks' solution of changing

```
git config --add C:\mydir\checkstyle.xml
```

to

```
git config --add C:\\mydir\\checkstyle.xml
```

worked.

Comment: I'm using Git Shell. I tried KurzedMetal's suggestion, but I'm getting the same exact result.

Comment: I downloaded the hook from here: [link](https://gist.github.com/davetron5000/37350). I renamed it to "pre-compile" and placed it in .git\hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git understands both slashes and backslashes.  To add backslashes, you must escape them.  So either of these commands will work.

```
git config --add checkstyle.jar C:/yourdir/checkstyle.jar
git config --add checkstyle.jar C:\\yourdir\\checkstyle.jar
```

You can check your configuration by viewing the file `.git/config`, you should see something like this:

```
[checkstyle]
        jar = C:/yourdir/checkstyle.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. At this point, the backslashes are showing up using the command "git config --add checkstyle.jar C:\\yourdir\\checkstyle.jar". In the config file, the directory looks something like C:\\\\yourdir\\\\checkstyle.jar (?). The hook documentation also claims to run "git config --add checkstyle.checkfile <location of checkfile>" which it claims is the checkstyle.xml file. Now I'm getting "Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile C:\Users\...". I'm going to try re-downloading the file and see if it works.

Comment: I don't follow.  Is there still a problem?  What's not working?

Comment: I downloaded checkstyle-5.7 from sourceforge and put checkstyle-5.7-all.jar and checkstyle_checks.xml in the correct folder. I'm still getting the error that the checkstyle_checks.xml is an "Invalid or corrupt jarfile". Again, the hook documentation says to add the xml file to git config.

Comment: [checkstyle]
 jar = C:\\\\mydir\\\\checkstyle-5.7-all.jar
 checkfile = C:\\\\mydir\\\\sun_checks.xml

Comment: both jar and checkfile are on newlines. Sorry about the formatting, new here.

Comment: Sorry been away for a while.  Can you update your pre-commit perl file to add `print "$command \n";` at line 45, and put the result here?  We'll have to take this to chat now, I think.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply myself. I somehow got it working, I honestly don't know what the issue was. All I did was re-copy the sun_checks.xml file over to the directory again and I was no longer receiving the error.